# Как получить текущее время?

Tags: python

Какой метод/модуль использовать, чтобы получить текущее время в Python?
<sup>[Перевод вопроса "How to get current time in Python"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/415511/6275986)</sup>

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/415511/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Импортируем модуль [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

```
>>> import datetime
```

Получаем дату:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now()
datetime(2009, 1, 6, 15, 8, 24, 78915)
```

Только время:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now())
datetime.time(15, 8, 24, 78915)
```

То же, только компактнее:

```
>>> datetime.datetime.now().time()
```

Быстрое представление

См. [документацию](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) по `datetime`.

---

Можно импортировать `datetime` объект из `datetime` модуля:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
```

Тогда можно убрать первый `datetime` из примеров:

```
datetime.datetime.now().time() => datetime.now().time()
```

---

Строковое представление можно получить из **[`time.strftime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/time.html?highlight=time.strftime#time.gmtime)** и **[`time.gmtime()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/time.html?highlight=time.strftime#time.gmtime)**:

```
>>> from time import gmtime, strftime
>>> strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", gmtime())
'2009-01-05 22:14:39'
```

Или даже так:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> str(datetime.now())
'2011-05-03 17:45:35.177000'
```

Comment: не копируйте бездумно код из других ответов. Уродливый код: `datetime.datetime.time(datetime.datetime.now())`. Следовало бы: `datetime.now().time()` вместо этого использовать (`from datetime import datetime`)